# How to allow custom TLS extensions in Client Hello from web Server

Tags: apache, ssl

when custom TLS extension added to Client Hello message, web Server respond with "ERR_SSL_DECRYPT_ERROR_ALERT". web server is running with Apache. is there any guide to define custom extension in Server side.

[Screenshot after add the custom extension. Last one is the custom added extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbp2M.png)

[Message Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4oML.png)

Comment: A proper TLS server will ignore extensions it does not understand. Probably something else is wrong with your ClientHello. Unfortunately, no details are available in your question to further look into the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to add custom extension as follows. type :1000 ,Length: 17 , Data: xxxxxxxxx; Type 1000 is unassigned according to https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not make it reproducible. The problem might be in the way how you've added the extension, not in the extension itself.

Comment: Hi, i have added screenshot of extension i tried. when i remove custom field, page works fine. when i insert and send, server gives error "Decrypt error".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbp2M.png

Comment: Do i need to add custom extension before "padding" ?

Comment: I don't see any requirement for adding a custom extension before padding. Unfortunately you only show screenshots here. It is still not clear how you add the extension. For example adding the extension by some man in the middle will not work since the client would then have a different idea of the ClientHello message than the server.

Comment: custom extension added by middle network device. Original client Hello modified by middle device and send to the server.

Comment: Greetings @user1542853. Have you managed to solve this? I have the same problem and I have not figured out how to: 1) Modify my Apache configuration; and 2) Write an application to read values from the custom extension.

Answer (score 0):

> Original client Hello modified by middle device and send to the server.

TLS is designed to prevent any modification by a man in the middle. This includes modifications of the handshake which are detected because the final Finished message contains a protected hash over all handshake messages.

It is therefore not possible to simply add a TLS extension by some middle device and expect the handshake to be successful. The error you see reflects that the server detected a manipulation of the handshake messages.

Comment: Deep packet inspection devices can add TLS extensions in the client hello message. You have to configure the WebServer to accept these custom values - we're trying to figure out how!

Comment: @hq: This is not about accepting extensions by the peer but about violating the integrity of the communication. The TLS handshake is cryptographically protected against any changes. Both client and server will include a (kind of) HMAC over all send and received data during the handshake. If someone changes packets in between such change will be noticed and the TLS session abandoned before any application data are exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Image that contains the supported_versions extension, your client is supporting TLS1.3(but not the server I guess)

Based on TLS1.3 documentation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-4.2

The error may be happening because the server is expecting to see pre_shared_key extension as the last one

An additional hint: after the client/server key exchange, you should see the "New Session Ticket" packet and the failure happened in that place.

Example of correct flow https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/26fa735868c1